# algorithm to calculate speeds to move in order to arrive in x turns

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

given a `distance`, `turns` calculate the number of turns to be on each speed - 1 2 4, and 8. to complete the distance on the last turn.

you start on speed 1, and in each turn you can accelerate to the next speed or do nothing (1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 8), once you accelerate you can't slow back down.

each turn you are moving `speed` steps (distance -= speed).

also, it's ok to go more than `distance` steps but only if it happens on the last turn.

for example: distance = 25, turns = 10 -> speed 1: 1 turn, speed 2: 5 turns, speed 4: 4 turns, the total distance is 1 * 1 + 2 * 5 + 4 * 4 = 27 steps, but we got to 25 steps on the last turn which is what we need.

I need help writing a function that will calculate that.

```
def calc_speeds(distance: int, arrive_in_x_turns: int) -> dict[int, int]:
```

so far i've used this `turns_till_arrival = ((turns_till_arrival - (speed // 2)) // speed) + (speed // 2) + 1` formula, in a for loop, for each `speed` and if `turns_till_arrival` is equal to `turns` I will accelerate until I get to `speed` without spending extra turns in other speeds (only the 1 necessary turn, because **I can only accelerate once per turn**) but then there are a lot of times that it doesn't work because in order for it to work I must spend more than 1 turn at other speeds but I can't figure out a way to calculate that.

Comment: it's not homework it's for a coding game I participate in @JohnnyJohnBoy

Comment: What's the input and what's the desired output? I don't follow the question and game or homework, you've not explained what you've tried, what worked/didn't work etc.

Comment: the input is the distance between 2 places & the number of turns in which I need to complete this distance (not before not after). the output is the number of turns I need to in each speed in order to complete the distance in the given turns @JohnnyJohnBoy

Comment: and like I said, in the last turn you can surpass the distance but only if it happens on the last turn

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: I've updated the question and added what I've tried at the end @Jean-BaptisteYunès

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly exhaustive approach, but it does provide the correct answer to the problem above about how to cover your distance in a specified number of steps.

For my method, I first created the output dictionary in the form of `{1: distance, 2: 0, 4: 0, 8: 0}`, where, for each key-value pair, the key represents your speed and the value represents the total number of turns spent at that speed. This dictionary above represents the way to cover your distance in the maximum number of turns possible, since each turn you are just running at `speed=1`.

The important realization here is that if you subtract two turns from `output[1]` and add a turn to `output[2]`, you are covering the same distance as before, but you have lost a turn. Therefore, you can make a loop that stops when the number of turns in your output equals `arrive_in_x_turns`, and during each iteration, you lose a turn by doing the subprocess I have described above. This also works for the other speeds (i.e. subtracting two turns from `output[2]` and adding a turn into `output[4]` maintains the distance you want to travel while losing a turn).

Here is my implementation below. When running your example of `calc_speeds(distance=25, arrive_in_x_turns=10)`, my output is `{1: 1, 2: 6, 4: 3, 8: 0}`. The number of turns are correct (1 + 6 + 3 = 10), as is the distance covered (1*1 + 2*6 + 4*3 + 8*0 = 1 + 12 + 12 + 0 = 25).

```
def calc_speeds(distance: int, arrive_in_x_turns: int) -> dict[int, int]:
    output = {1: distance, 2: 0, 4: 0, 8: 0}

    # Loop until the total number of turns is equal to the number of turns requested
    while (sum(output.values()) > arrive_in_x_turns):
        # Subtract two turns off of '1' and add a turn to '2' until not possible
        # This method ensures that during each iteration, number of turns decreases
        # by one while the distance traveled remains the same
        if output[1] // 2 > 0:
            output[1] -= 2
            output[2] += 1
        # Do a similar method for the ones above
        elif output[2] // 2 > 0:
            output[2] -= 2
            output[4] += 1
        elif output[4] // 2 > 0:
            output[4] -= 2
            output[8] += 1
    
    return output
```

Again, this is an exhaustive solution that will have a long runtime with harder examples, but hopefully this will help get you started on finding a more optimal way to solve it!

**EDIT:**

This answer above can be optimized! Instead of subtracting two turns from a current speed and adding one turn to the next, we can instead find the minimum between half the number of turns of the current speed and the remaining number of turns that need to be gotten rid of. Here's a newer version.

```
def calc_speeds(distance: int, arrive_in_x_turns: int) -> dict[int, int]:
    output = {1: distance, 2: 0, 4: 0, 8: 0}

    # Loop until the total number of turns is equal to the number of turns requested
    while sum(output.values()) > arrive_in_x_turns:
        if output[1] // 2 > 0:
            # Calculate turns to subtract from current speed as the minimum between half the 
            # current turns under this speed and the number of turns remaining
            turns_to_subtract = min(output[1] // 2, sum(output.values()) - arrive_in_x_turns)
            # Use similar logic to the previous version of this algorithm
            output[1] -= turns_to_subtract * 2
            output[2] += turns_to_subtract
        elif output[2] // 2 > 0:
            turns_to_subtract = min(output[2] // 2, sum(output.values()) - arrive_in_x_turns)
            output[2] -= turns_to_subtract * 2
            output[4] += turns_to_subtract
        elif output[4] // 2 > 0:
            turns_to_subtract = min(output[4] // 2, sum(output.values()) - arrive_in_x_turns)
            output[4] -= turns_to_subtract * 2
            output[8] += turns_to_subtract
    
    return output
```

Comment: **I must spend at least 1 turn in each speed before I can accelerate**, and let's say I pass these parameters to your function `calc_speeds(28, 6)`, I get `{1: 0, 2: 0, 4: 5, 8: 1}` which is impossible because according to this I need to go to speed 8 without ever being in speeds 1, 2

Comment: and I can surpass the distance provided to the function,  but only if it happens in the last turn, let's say I need to go 25 steps in 6 turns, it's ok to go 24 in 5 and in the 6th get to a total of 31, `{1: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, 8: 3}`  is a valid output for input of `calc_speeds(25, 6)`

Comment: Oh I see...I'll try to adjust my answer to add a condition to account for what you mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: I've figured out how to modify your code in order to fit my first and second comment, thanks for your help, I've accepted your answer

Comment: @OmerDagry that's awesome! I was struggling to find those modifications; would you be able to post them here as an answer/follow-up comment? I'm curious to see what you did.

Comment: yes, I've uploaded it to pastebin, `https://pastebin.com/hdVzU8WM`